# Visual Studio 6 Processor Pack Enabling SSE2

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

How do I enable the SSE2 instruction set in MSVC 6.0 with SP5 and Processor Pack installed?

I was expecting to see a compiler option under Project Settings | C++ | Code Generation, as I'm used to on MSVC2005. But I don't. Is it via command line only?

Comment: +1 for hearing confirmation that someone is still using VS6. for C++ development.  Awesome.

Comment: @AJ. **NSIS** project uses VS 6.0 for compatibility with Win 98. Check http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixG.html So there are strong reason to use legacy build toolchain ((

Answer (score 2):

I thought I remembered a flag, but if you use intrinsics (_mm_div_ss and __m128 etc), then just #include "xmmintrin.h" (use chevrons) for SSE2 support.

If I can find an old project, I will check but if you prefer vs6 (as I do), you can use the Intel compiler.

Although I use 2005, 2008 and 2010 at work on a daily basis, vs6 is my preferred option for working on a netbook on the go.

I also recommend Perforce free 2 user version for local backups with vs6 integration.

By the way, only install sp5 with pp5, sp6 has no processor pack.